# Understanding high frequency tesla coil circuit

Tags: transformer, tesla-coil

Below is a circuit diagram for a high frequency tesla coil circuit that I found on this [site](https://acid-byte.info/class-e-tesla-coil-10-87mhz/). L2 is the primary winding and L3 is the secondary. My understanding of resonant transformers is that they should be electrically isolated, however, in this case the primary and the secondary are directly connected. Can anyone explain why this is necessary?

[image: High frequency tesla coil circuit]

Comment: There’s no rule that says resonant transformers must be electrically isolated. Where else would you connect the secondary?

Comment: I meant isolated from the primary

Comment: Yes, this is what I understood. Again, it is not unusual. It could be the primary is giving a ‘leg up’ for the secondary voltage wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding of resonant transformers is that they should be electrically isolated

No, they **can** be isolated. The low design coupling of a Tesla coil makes it easier to isolate them with a big air gap.

Tesla coils operated from the mains **must** be isolated for personal safety. If the long sparks from the secondary manage to contact you, the plasma channel could create a connection between you and the mains, and a lethal current could flow. People have died like this.

Battery operated Tesla coils don't need isolating for safety.

Solid State Tesla Coils (SSTCs) will need some form of feedback to the secondary so the sustaining device can maintain oscillation. Some coils use capacitive pickup for this, though a direct connection is usually easier to make work.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually my circuit design. If you look me up on facebook (acid byte)
We can talk about it.

The circuit consist out of a choke L1
A coil L2 to phase shift the power going to L3.
And L3 wich is a base driven resonator.
L2 and C1 form a resonant circuit to switch the gate of the mosfet. C1 and C2 make up for a capacitive voltage divider to step down the voltage going to the gate.